# myFieldHandle error in Craft using Smart Map

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I am getting a Twig runtime error on the below. The map and everything else works when I remove `myFieldHandle(params).orderBy('distance')`.

Error:

```
Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\EntryQuery::myFieldHandle()
```

Code:

```
{% set target = '90210' %}
{% set params = {
    target: target,
    range: 100
} %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('contractors').myFieldHandle(params).orderBy('distance') %}

{% set options = {
    height: 700,
    draggable: false,
    markerInfo: '_includes/mapInfoBubble',
    infoWindowOptions: {
        maxWidth: 250
    }
} %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The example of `myFieldHandle` is just a placeholder for your actual field handle.

So if your Address field has a handle of `address`, it would look something like this...

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('contractors').address(params).orderBy('distance') %}
```